# How to texture a downloaded model made of stretched triangles?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, geometry

I'm a beginner in blender. Trying to texture a 3d furniture model which was downloaded from the manufacturer site. Geometry is made of stretched triangles. This causes problems of stretched texture which is visible on render.

I unwrapped the model with "smart uv project" but the geometry is still stretched
Is there any solution to texture it properly or I need to remodel it to make it quads?

What if I need to use dozens of real furniture models like this? 
Should I model everything from scratch in blender?

some pictures to explain:enter image description here[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Triangulated UV map shouldn't be a problem. I'd check the model's normals and double vertices (typical problems on imported geometry).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Model's normal are ok - all highlighted blue on a face orientation preview. I've also cleared geometry doing: Mesh edit > selecting all> clean up > merge by disatnce which resulted in cleaning over 7k vertices. But there is still problem on my texture

Comment: Thank you ;) I'm not sure if it is ok if I put download link on wetransfer: https://we.tl/t-JgWgkM54AU

Comment: It looks like a CAD model, and they tend to be messy like this :).

Comment: I know that 3ds max(I'm not an expert either) is capable of covering such geometry with texture without visible seems. I wasn't sure if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: As I'm learning for the archviz I know there are dozens of furniture models with simmilar geometry. Is that mean you recomend remodelling all models in purpose to render it properly in blender?

Comment: Thank you very much ;). It clears geometry in render indeed ;) Do you think merging faces (like selecting two or more and pushing "F") or disolving edges are right thinking in therms of cleaning mesh?

Comment: Thank you very much! You've made my day ;) I've been struggling this for several days ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by N-gons and double vertices.

If you only need simple shading, go *Object > Shade flat* and disable *Autosmooth*.

[image]

You can also use *Mesh > Clean up > Limited dissolve* to merge flat faces.
Before any larger changes, the mesh should be properly repaired.

[image]