# Texture artefacts / distortions on mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, artifacts

New to blender, I imported a design from a CAD software using Mesh objects. I applied textures on the objects (to render object sides) and on Top and Bottom faces.

On the Top and bottom I have some artefacts and distortions on the texture. Furthermore, the texture scale seems also to changes along the parts...

Here is an example. It happens nearly on all the parts...

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Related: [How to texture a downloaded model made of stretched triangles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/180010/)

Comment: I tried the answer of the recommanded post, but it gives a strange result: Faces orignally on a same plane seems not to be anymore (shift+G normal or coplanar gives strange results.) Furthermore, rounds are faced...The solution would be to clean the polygones on a face. Is there a tool for that?