# Beginner: Dealing with normals to avoid ripples & artifacts

Tags: modeling, normals

I'm a beginner to blender. In the pictures below you can see how there is distortion around the windows and roof vents of this factory. With Unity, you can just click a box that says "calculate normals" and it fixes it. Everything becomes flat and there is no distortion. I'm using three.js and can't use this. Is there something I can do to prevent this distortion? I know I'm probably not modeling with best practices, but event the roof vents which have square faces are having distortion. Any help here? (the third pic is three.js)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share one of your objects (the central cube for example)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello :). Enabling *Autosmooth* should fix that. Related: [Stretched triangle shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/180010/78972)

Comment: Thanks Jachym! Autosmooth did not work but the Shader Flat solution in the link provided did.